# Transferring data from event listener to controller

Tags: php, symfony

I have set up a before event listener in the IndexBundle. The event listener takes some data from an xml file. That data needs to be used in the controller associated with the event listener. So, how do i transfer the data from event listener to controller?

Also, how can i make a global event listener that is not going to be associated to any bundle but to all of them? I tried using multiple class arguments in the app/config.yml like this...

```
language_listener:
         class: Hotel\IndexBundle\EventListener\LanguageEventListener
         class: Hotel\KontaktBundle\EventListener\LanguageEventListener
         tags:
             - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method:     onKernelController }
```

and it works but, the code in the event listener that collects xml data is generic and has to take all the data, even if the executing bundle won't use it. Say I have a "name" tag in the xml file. The "name" tag is used in the IndexBundle and not in KontaktBundle but every time an event listener gets executed, it takes the dana from the "name" tag, regardles of the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the event listener executes globaly by default, no matter in what bundle you put it in. So, if the event listener is in the Acme/AcmeBundle/EventListener directory, he will execute in every bundle if you register it in the app/config.yml.

But i still don't know if there is a transparent way of transfering data acquried in the event listener to the currently executing controller. One way is sessions but the question is, is there a built-in symfony way of doing it.

That question remains.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer by myself. The way to get the values from event listener to the controller is trough service container. The service container objects are instantieted only once so changing an object (that I got from the service container) in the event listener will result in the same object in the controller.